# Is this a javascript closure?

Tags: javascript, function, closures

I have this....

```
function MyFunction() {
    var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    this.getMyVar = function() {
        return myVar;
    }
}

var myProperty = new MyFunction();
console.log(myProperty.getMyVar());

myProperty.myVar = "you're not encapsulated";
console.log(myProperty.getMyVar());
```

It outputs: "I think I am encapsulated twice".  Why?  I did not think this was a closure...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The closure is around the "getMyVar" function. The variable "myVar" **inside** the constructor is a local variable, and **not** visible outside the function except as the return value from "getMyVar".

Setting a "myVar" property on the object does just that, but the "getMyVar" function is not returning a property of an object; it's returning the value of the local variable in the closure.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

When you define a function inside of another function, the inner function has access to ***all*** of the outer function's local variables...

In your case, `getMyVar` has access to `myVar` - through the closure.

Answer (score 2):

```
var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

this.getMyVar = function() {
    return myVar;
}
```

This is a closure, and the `myVar` variable **from the time the function was created** will be returned. Notice that's it a local variable, so there's no other way to access it after this function exits.

```
var myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";
```

Notice that this is not `this.myVar` (the variable you're setting later with `myProperty.myVar`).

Probably what you're trying to do is:

```
function MyFunction() {
    this.myVar = "I think I am encapsulated";

    this.getMyVar = function() {
        return this.myVar;
    }
}
```